# Return statement being skipped

Tags: java, android, if-statement, return

I have a recyclerview which is meant to show transactions but seperated by their dates. However my getItemViewType doesnt seem to work. This is the code:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        if (mCompareDate == null || !fmt.format(mTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition).getTime()).equals(fmt.format(mCompareDate))) {
            mCompareDate = mTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition).getTime();
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

I have an if statement that checks a value, however when I run it, it crashes. I didnt have an 'else if' statement before, but I was hoping it would help the crash, an else statement should work fine.

Anyway I debugged it and watch it step by step and the program seems to find that the first statement is correct, it then does everything inside the statement including the 'return 2;' however afterwards it just skips to return 0, which results in a crash, if I didnt have the else if then it would skips straight into the else statement and return 1, also crashing it.

edit: Fixed the else if statement for confusion issues.

further edit: Because confusion was not fixed, here is a gif of what i mean https://gyazo.com/06d2de58e7c170f0cbbf1a4e58be7ca3

Comment: You need to post a stack trace or more code, this is fine.

Comment: You need to check if (mTransactions == null) and if (mTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition) == null)

Comment: @DominiqueLorre I watched the debugger go through it, neither of those statements are true. It literally reads that the if statement is correct, goes to the return 2 line then continues to the else and returns that value instead.

Comment: Can you clarify "it crashes"?

Comment: Well it crash is expected, the statement returns the incorrect value for some reason which makes the program crash later on, however the statement shouldnt be returning the wrong value at all as it shows in my gif.

Comment: Do not trust the debugger! Use log statements inside and outside the `if-else` to check what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using switch instead of multiple if else if : anyway 
      once return 1 is executed later part of code is dead code so it won't execute  .. You can use continue and break statement to have control on conditional statement
     adding please post your exception/logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem, you are not getting the `if` `else if` concept properly. When `if` condition is once returned true, other else if are not checked.

And the second problem

One function can only return once. You are explicitly returning at the end `return 0` which is not valid. So, your program crashes.

Have a good time

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I know how to use the else if, I merely tried it to fix the issue, the original code was just else because either it is or it isnt, however it would always go into the else statement even if the if statement was true and I had watched the debugger go through the if statement onto the return 2 field and then onto the else.

Comment: I just told you the reason due to which your code was crashed

Comment: No you didnt, it crashes with or without the else if statement, I have said that twice now. The else if was merely something I tried because it was going through the if code, seeing the if code was correct, running the return 2 code and then proceeding to go to the else statement and the return 1 statement.

Comment: @JamesGreen You're not going to get an answer because you're extremely unclear. You mentioned it crashed but them apparently this mysterious "crash" isnt actually what you are asking about, you're actually asking about something to do with 1 vs 2, then you threw in mention of a 0 which is nowhere in your code, and we have no idea what you're *expected* vs *actual* results are, what these other vars are in your code, or what your end goal even is. So please, if you want a useful answer, write a useful question instead of confusing everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return view type int in range 0 to viewCount - 1.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    if (mCompareDate == null || !fmt.format(mTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition).getTime()).equals(fmt.format(mCompareDate))) {
        mCompareDate = mTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition).getTime();
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, you don't make use of position in your method. An AdapterView needs to scroll forwards and backwards and access the Views in whatever order it wants to. I'm not sure how you're managing things outside this method but it looks like you're expecting the Adapter to iterate sequentially...

ANOTHER EDIT: This will require changes elsewhere in your Adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    if (position == 0 || !fmt.format(mTransactions.get(position).getTime()
            .equals(fmt.format(mTransactions.get(position - 1).getTime())) {
        // First transaction on this date (probably want to give it a header?)
        return 1;
    else {
        // transaction on same date as previous in list
        return 0;
    }
}
```

FINAL EDIT: Because the DateViews you want aren't elements in the List, I suggest forgetting entirely about getItemViewType(). Give your TransactionView a heading equivalent to your DateView with an id so you can set visibility to GONE or VISIBLE.

Then in onBindViewHolder():

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
if (position == 0 || !fmt.format(mTransactions.get(position).getTime()
        .equals(fmt.format(mTransactions.get(position - 1).getTime())) {
    // First transaction on this date (probably want to give it a header?)
    holder.heading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.heading.setText(fmt.format(mTransactions.get(position).getTime());
else {
    // transaction on same date as previous in list
    holder.heading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
// Fill in other details of TransactionView here
```

Comment: Didnt work. Thanks though. Check the gif in the question, should explain better.

Comment: The problem with using the actual position is that the idea behind it means that there will be multiple transactions and the days will be seperated, so for example if I did on on the 16th then there would be a DateViewHolder that would display this. However this would potentially ruin the position based system of accessing the Transaction information. Thus I have a transactionPosition field which increments only when a transactionViewHolder is created. Therefore the position doesnt mess up the mTransactions array.

Comment: But what happens when you scroll backwards through the list?

Comment: So you want a row for each date?

Comment: Good point, I dont know how else I would do it mind you. Using position wouldnt work with the way I can think of doing it. Say I had three values in the mTransactions all on different days. If I had it doing it through position then it would expect mTransactions to have 6 values.

Comment: I see, great way of doing it, thanks, I will do it that way, unfortunately it doesn't answer why the code was acting so weird, thanks for the help!